# Python upload PDF into MySQL database via PHP web service

Tags: php, python, mysql

I'm trying to upload a file to a php script running on server via a python script:

PYTHON CODE:

```
file = open(new_alert.alarmpdfurl, 'rb').read()
r = requests.post('https://www.firerun.at/dbadmin.php?'+data,files={'file':('alarmpdf.pdf', file)})
```

The problem is I can not find the file in the $_POST or $_SERVER variables.
The question is how do I get the file in the PHP script to upload it to my MySQL DB as BLOB.

Comment: Have you checked `$_FILES`?

Comment: Yes the files seems to be there. but how do I get it into a blob in my database

Comment: As a general rule I'd say don't save PDFs into MySQL blobs, but if you must then it's an entirely different question you're asking. There's plenty of help that can be found online about writing BLOBs to MySQL tables. Google is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

$_FILES

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php

Similar to $_POST, but specific to uploaded files.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you need to read the contents of the uploaded file first, using a function like file_get_contents("absolute-path-to-uploaded-file").

The value of "absolute-path-to-uploaded-file" should be in the $_FILES array.

The value returned by file_get_contents function can be saved to the blob column in MySQL database